# Why is it a good practice to make a final field pointing to an immutable obj non public?

Tags: java, effective-java

effective java has a statement about the access control:
Even if a field is final and refers to an immutable object, by making it public you give up the flexibility to switch to a new internal data representation in which the field does not exist.

I don't understand what it means. Appreciate if someone can explain.

Comment: If some other code relies on the fact that a final field is, for example, an `ArrayList` and we want to change it to another `List`-implementationn, the other code will break.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for your comments. But final field pointing to an immutable obj is something can never be changed right?

Comment: It ties other code into implementation. Were you to change the class so the field no longer exists, there would be issues.

Comment: We can always change the type in the source code. That is what Josh Bloch is talking about.

Comment: @pnpjunction It can't be changed *while the program is running*. But when your boss comes and says "hey, requirements have changed!", then someone has to go update the code. `final` won't save your variable from the backspace key of a future programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike newer languages like Kotlin and Scala, Java makes a very clear distinction between fields and methods. So if you've got a

```
public final Foo foo;
```

Then that's always pointing to an *actual* field in memory. It can never be a method, and it can never run arbitrary code. The call `myInstance.foo` is *always* direct memory access, which is contrary to OOP principles. When I ask an instance for something, it should be the instance's decision how to handle that request, not mine.

In Kotlin, properties can have [getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html), so even if we have something that *looks* like a field, it might call a method to access it. This allows us to future-proof our code in advance. We can implement an actual instance variable *now*,

```
val foo: Foo = myConcreteInstance()
```

and then, down the road, when `foo` needs to go make a database query or something because we're scaling our application up, we can change the implementation

```
val foo: Foo
  get() = loadFooLazily()

private fun loadFooLazily(): Foo {
  // Some complicated code ...
}
```

Crucially, this affects *nobody* downstream. Everybody else downstream still writes `myInstance.foo` and works with the new code. It's not a breaking change.

We can't do this in Java. `myInstance.foo` is *always* a variable, not a method. So Effective Java suggests always accessing instance variables through a method in order to future-proof them. If we write

```
private final Foo foo;

public Foo getFoo() {
  return foo;
}
```

Then we can change `getFoo` in the future without breaking other code. It's a difference in philosophy: In Java, methods are the OOP construct while instance variables are strictly an implementation detail. In most newer languages, "instance variable" has been replaced with a high-level construct called a "property" which is intended to be used in an OOP way.